# Error in KSOAP Parsing :- java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.SoapFault

Tags: java, android, ksoap

I have a little knowledge in ksoap Parsing. When i am parsing some data it gives Error :

`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.SoapFault`

I can see the response for that method in [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) but when i parsing that method in android it gives an error as like above.

Here is Request parameter as input in SoapUI

```
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
           <tem:SaveChangePasswordForExternalUser>
              <tem:userId>Test123</tem:userId>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <tem:oldPassword>TestTest</tem:oldPassword>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <tem:newPassword>Test</tem:newPassword>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <tem:retypedNewPassword>Test</tem:retypedNewPassword>
           </tem:SaveChangePasswordForExternalUser>
        </soapenv:Body>
     </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here Is Response i got in SoapUI

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Old Password was incorrectly entered. Remember that passwords are case-sensitive.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
               <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
               <Message>Old Password was incorrectly entered. Remember that passwords are case-sensitive.</Message>       
               <Type>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException</Type>
            </ExceptionDetail>
         </detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This how i try to get the response by code in android

```
public void getData()
    {

        private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/"; //
        private static final String URL = "http://173.203.136.194:99/LeaseWave.MobileApplication.Service/MobileApplicationService.svc/basic";
        private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IMobileApplicationService/SaveChangePasswordForExternalUser";
        private static final String METHOD_NAME = "SaveChangePasswordForExternalUser";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("userId", "Test123");
        request.addProperty("oldPassword", "TestTest");
        request.addProperty("newPassword", "Test");
        request.addProperty("newPassword", "Test");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

            Log.i("Long...", "Response  ------ "+resultsRequestSOAP);


        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

but i don't get success in that. 
Anyone have any kind of hint or solution for this?

Comment: webservice is returning what, int,string or any object?

Comment: your code is quite ok. I think problem is in NAMESPACE,URL,SOAP_ACTION,METHOD_NAME declaration.

Comment: @himanshu This works smoothly for other methods but here in response it give the tag <s:Fault> it creates problem. You have any solution or hint for that i done googling much but don't get a satisfaction.

Comment: provide the code of SaveChangePasswordForExternalUser() method.

Comment: @himanshu as i written above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

when you are dealing with SOAP Web Service, This problem may come some time.
The response coming from the service can either be a **SOAP Object** and if something goes wrong like wrong credentials passed then Response comes with error message and it's a **SOAPFAULT Object**. So update your code of parsing to check the type of the response object.

This sort of code can solve your problem,

```
    if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
        String str= ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
        Log.i("", str);

        // Another way to travers through the SoapFault object
    /*  Node detailsString =str= ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).detail; 
        Element detailElem = (Element) details.getElement(0) 
                     .getChild(0); 
        Element e = (Element) detailElem.getChild(2);faultstring; 
        Log.i("", e.getName() + " " + e.getText(0)str); */
    } else {
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        Log.d("WS", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make changes:::

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("tem:userId", UserId);
        request.addProperty("tem:oldPassword",OldPasssword);
        request.addProperty("tem:newPassword", NewPassword);
        request.addProperty("tem:retypedNewPassword", NewPasswordAgain);
```

You need to pass the exact Tag names to put the values in the method of Webservice, its like specifing the values to exact arguments names of a method.

Let me know if have any more issues.

Comment: thanks for reply but this not works. Can you give any other ideas.

Comment: @SteveDesai: can u give me the url of webservice location, i mean where i can see the stuff :: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
        <soapenv:Header/>.... etc

Comment: i am asking because i found your URL wrong, its not what you need as for webservice and moreover SOAP ACTION is like URL+method_name whereas you have different url of Soap Action.

Comment: URL and method name works fine in my other methods but the problem comes when than the response come with tab <s:Fault>.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is here:

```
Log.i("Long...", "Response  ------ "+resultsRequestSOAP);
```

ClassCastException is possibly because of silent casting of SOAP object "resultsRequesSOAP" to string. I am not sure if .toString() will work but try returning something and get it by using getProperty() method of SOAPObject. See if that Works.

If not please post error logs and debug and see where exactly is the problem. Which line...

Comment: yes You are right error comes there on log. I try bu .toString but it not works. Other suggestions are acceptable. Error come same as i posted as above.

Comment: A simple question why do you want to log it? ... Just perform your operations... And if you want to see something in log... just return a string value in your webMethod and retrieve it using resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString(). Hope this helps

Comment: If in log it give a response that all the things are fine.

Comment: dude... if response is fine, all things are fine the where is classCastException ?

Comment: here is little misunderstanding dear you tell me "if you want to see something in log... just return a string value in your webMethod and retrieve it using resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString()." but even m not get the response than how can i get property of that? Thats y my told that "If in log it give a response that all the things are fine. "

Comment: yes indeed there is a misunderstanding. you are getting the response you are just not able to type cast it. you getting my point? Check your server logs to see if everything is fine and then check your device or emulator logs. And please use English...